# Import websocketpp for cmake in VS2017

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, websocket++

I am trying to import websocket++ to my project in Visual Studio 2017, but I have got a lot of errors with using it.

Project structure:

```
MyProject
  - src
    - websocketpp
    CMakeLists.txt
    echo_server.cpp
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(MyProject)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/websocketpp)

add_executable(MyProject echo_server.cpp)
```

echo_server.cpp looks like:

```
#include "websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp"

#include "websocketpp/server.hpp"

#include <iostream>

typedef websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio> server;

using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

// pull out the type of messages sent by our config
typedef server::message_ptr message_ptr;

// Define a callback to handle incoming messages
void on_message(server* s, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg) {
    std::cout << "on_message called with hdl: " << hdl.lock().get()
              << " and message: " << msg->get_payload()
              << std::endl;

    // check for a special command to instruct the server to stop listening so
    // it can be cleanly exited.
    if (msg->get_payload() == "stop-listening") {
        s->stop_listening();
        return;
    }

    try {
        s->send(hdl, msg->get_payload(), msg->get_opcode());
    } catch (websocketpp::exception const & e) {
        std::cout << "Echo failed because: "
                  << "(" << e.what() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Create a server endpoint
    server echo_server;

    try {
        // Set logging settings
        echo_server.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        echo_server.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::frame_payload);

        // Initialize Asio
        echo_server.init_asio();

        // Register our message handler
        echo_server.set_message_handler(bind(&on_message,&echo_server,::_1,::_2));

        // Listen on port 9002
        echo_server.listen(9002);

        // Start the server accept loop
        echo_server.start_accept();

        // Start the ASIO io_service run loop
        echo_server.run();
    } catch (websocketpp::exception const & e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "other exception" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E1696   cannot open source file
>   "websocketpp/config/core.hpp" MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\websocketpp\config\asio_no_tls.hpp   31
>   Error (active)    E1696   cannot open source file
>   "websocketpp/transport/asio/endpoint.hpp" MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\websocketpp\config\asio_no_tls.hpp   32
>   Error (active)    E1696   cannot open source file
>   "websocketpp/roles/server_endpoint.hpp"   MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\websocketpp\server.hpp   31
>   Error (active)    E0283   qualified name is not allowed   MyProject -
>   x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  7
>   Error (active)    E0065   expected a ';'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  7
>   Error (active)    E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or
>   namespace name    MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  9
>   Error (active)    E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or
>   namespace name    MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  10
>   Error (active)    E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or
>   namespace name    MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  11
>   Error (active)    E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or
>   namespace name    MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  14
>   Error (active)    E0070   incomplete type is not allowed  MyProject -
>   x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  17
>   Error (active)    E0020   identifier "server" is undefined    MyProject -
>   x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  17
>   Error (active)    E0020   identifier "s" is undefined MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  17
>   Error (active)    E0018   expected a ')'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  17
>   Error (active)    E0065   expected a ';'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  17
>   Error (active)    E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type
>   specifier MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  43
>   Error (active)    E0065   expected a ';'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  43
>   Error (active)    E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type
>   specifier MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  44
>   Error (active)    E0065   expected a ';'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  44
>   Error (active)    E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type
>   specifier MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  47
>   Error (active)    E0065   expected a ';'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  47
>   Error (active)    E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type
>   specifier MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  50
>   Error (active)    E0065   expected a ';'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  50
>   Error (active)    E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type
>   specifier MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  53
>   Error (active)    E0065   expected a ';'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  53
>   Error (active)    E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type
>   specifier MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  56
>   Error (active)    E0065   expected a ';'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  56
>   Error (active)    E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type
>   specifier MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  59
>   Error (active)    E0065   expected a ';'  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  59
>   Error (active)    E0169   expected a declaration  MyProject - x64-Debug
>   (default) G:_Development\Projects\MyProject\src\echo_server.cpp  60
>   Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'websocketpp/config/core.hpp':
>   No such file or directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\src\CMakeLists.txt   g:_development\projects\myproject\src\websocketpp\config\asio_no_tls.hpp   31

What is wrong? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the implementation of websocketpp, importing it into your project should be quite simple.

Start by downloading websocketpp and install it:

```
git clone https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp.git && cd websocketpp
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=some/known/path ..
cmake --build . --target install
```

Do not forget the `..` in the command. It's the relative path to the source directory from the build directory.

The `some/known/path` can be a global path on your machine, in the user's directory or even inside a specific directory in your project.

Also, since this library export the package into the user's package registry, you can skip the install and let cmake import the build tree as the package itself. I usually find installing them to be cleaner however.

```
cmake --build .
```

Then inside your project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(MyProject)

find_package(websocketpp REQUIRED)

add_executable(MyProject echo_server.cpp)

# Link include directories, libraries, defines etc.
target_link_libraries(MyProject PUBLIC websocketpp::websocketpp)
```

You can then invoke cmake like this:

```
# inside your-project/build
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=some/known/path ..
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have got error: G:\_Development\Projects\CPP_Sources\websocketpp\build>cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=G:/_Development/Projects/MyProject
CMake Error: The source directory "G:/_Development/Projects/CPP_Sources/websocketpp/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: You forgot the `..` in the command. It specify the relative path from the build directory to the source

Comment: Builded well now, but package not found now. CMake Error CMakeLists.txt (find_package):
  By not providing "Findwebsocketpp.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "websocketpp", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "websocketpp" with
  any of the following names:

    websocketppConfig.cmake
    websocketpp-config.cmake

Comment: Hmm... I'm surprised here. The library exports the package correctly and if you also set the prefix path to be the same, it should work

Comment: I did add that directory to env variable path in windows and now it works. Thank you so much!